# will PostgreSQL optimize LIKE '%'?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I wonder if `SELECT * FROM foo` will execute faster than `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name LIKE '%'` assuming name is NOT NULL?

Any references to documentation?

Comment: Why haven't you tried to execute both queries and check the results yourself?

Comment: b/c how it performs on someone's machine doesn't answer the question, what matters is how it's supposed to work in theory - do they have this kind of optimization implemented or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your queries will scan the entire table.  Whether or not name is NOT NULL is only important in extremely rare circumstances where there is (1) an index on name and (2) it is *very, very* sparse.   Only then will PostgreSQL consider looking up the records from the name index.

In all other situations, this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f0e91/1/1) shows that the LIKE version adds a filter, which must be checked.  PostgreSQL has no optimization to remove `LIKE '%'` against a not-null varchar column, as much as it seems sensible.

### Table SELECT * all rows

```
QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on foo (cost=0.00..15.00 rows=1000 width=62)
```

### Table SELECT * all rows with `LIKE '%'`

```
QUERY PLAN
Seq Scan on foo (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=1000 width=62)
Filter: ((name)::text ~~ '%'::text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Using LIKE requires the database to do a full table scan, in addition to simply returning the rows.

Comment: Even if it's LIKE '%'? Can't this condition just get ignored?

Comment: AFAIK, some LIKE implementations can use indexes if the pattern is anchored at the beginning (e.g. `c like 'pancakes%'`) so "LIKE requires a table scan" is overly broad.